# Why is, for example, the theory of ordinary differential equations considered less pure than number theory?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

This is a bit of a soft question, but why is it that number theory is considered the most "pure" branch of mathematics, and something like, say, the theory of differential equations, considered less "pure"? In my view, since real numbers (and hence real functions) can be derived from the set of natural numbers (via the well-known process of constructing the set of integers from the set of naturals, constructing the set of rationals from the set of integers, and finally constructing the set of reals from the set of rationals), the theory of differential equations is no less and no more "pure" than number theory. I am basically interested in the historical/sociological reason why certain subfields of even so-called "pure" mathematics are themselves considered more or less "pure" than other subfields.

Comment: The pure/applied distinction refers to how useful the subject is in areas outside of math, typically physics, engineering, or other sciences (chemistry, biology, etc.). Every physicist and chemist, and even biologist, will have come across differential equations in their work, but not so for number theory. It's a lot more important to those scientists to understand how some quantity changes over time (heat/particle diffusion, or wave movement, or reactions between chemicals, or population fluctuation), compared to how many ways there are to write a number as a sum of some powers, for instance.

Comment: There is also something of a difference in practice – since applied mathematics can be tested against reality sometimes arguments are based on intuition rather than axioms.

Comment: I'll add since no one has pointed it out. The notion of "pure" comes with elitism attached (at least historically and as late as 2015 when i was in college). The idea being math is purer than science and therefore harder/better/smarter. And then in math this culture tended to congregate in less applied subjects with the idea being working on number-theory or abstract-algebra or algebraic-geometry was more "hardcore" than PDES or Numerical analysis etc... I think this culture is nonsensical and at the top of the fields experts don't care but undergrads will pretend to care sometimes.

Comment: At some level this was probably Gauss's fault with the quote "Math is the Queen of the sciences" and "Number Theory is the Queen of mathematics". That was meant as a statement of beauty and continuity and fundamentalness but it ended up shaping the culture in negative ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various connotations & meanings of the relevant words. Here I am using a Dictionary to get the meanings of the Words.

Partial list [ WordWeb ] :

**PURE 1** : Concerned with theory and data rather than practice

**PURE 2** : Free of extraneous elements of any kind

**APPLIED 3** : Concerned with concrete problems or data rather than with fundamental principles

**APPLIED 4** : Put into service to work for a particular purpose or use as designed

In Mathematics , generally we use meanings "PURE 1" & "APLLIED 3" (or "APLLIED 4") not "PURE 2"

In that way , we have PURE Number theory or PURE Calculus or PURE theory of ODE or PURE Combinatorics , which may then have usage in the Sciences where it may become APPLIED ODE or APPLIED Combinatorics.